# Access 2013 using a lookup field with multiple values

Tags: ms-access, database-design, many-to-many, relational-database, lookup-tables

I'm using a database which contains a Staff table and a Groups table, what I'm trying to do is so that each staff member can be a member of many groups and each group can contain multiple staff, many-to-many relationship. I also have a join table connecting the two (below is my table structure). Both the Staff and the Groups table have a one-to-many relationship with the Group Staff table.

Staff Table

```
Staff ID
First Name
Last Name
```

Group Table

```
Group ID
Group Name
```

Group Staff Table

```
Group Staff ID - PK
Group ID - FK
Staff ID - FK
```

What I'm trying to do is in the Groups Table, I have a field called "Members" which should contain all the staff (looked up from the staff table) who are members of the group. I'm using a lookup field to display all the Staff members. The problem is that I can't select multiple staff for each group, which I need to.

If I try and change the lookup field to "Allow multiple values" then it tells me I can't because of the relationship between the Staff and the Group table, but of course I need the relationship to be able to lookup the Staff members.

So how can I make it so I can can have a lookup field in the Group table that allows me to select multiple Staff from the Staff Table? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it the way you've describe.

With a `Group` and `Staff` table, if you want a many-to-many relationship, you do (as you state) have to have a joining table (`GroupStaff`). However, you can't really create the relationships on either the `Group` or `Staff` tables.

You have to create new rows in the `GroupStaff` table. You can do this manually on row at a time, of if I'm creating a an app, I'll generally have a form with two sub forms. The parent form would be bound to `Group` in this case, and the subforms would be bound to `Staff` and `GroupStaff` respectively. You can then add controls (buttons) to add records to the `GroupStaff` table base on what records were selected in the `Group` form and the `Staff` subform.

The `GroupStaff` subform would also be filtered to show only the records associated with the group currently on the parent from.

Comment: In the end I just added the values manually in the GroupStaff Table and then used a subform to display it